# Slow queries on SQL Server 2008 with PHP while .Net application is closed

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database, which was created and is still working for a .Net application.

I have recently developed a new interface based on PHP to add new features and improve the old application.

The problem is that when the .Net application is closed, queries through PHP are very very slow, but when the .Net application is open, all queries are fast, and I have no idea of what can be happening.

I am using Laravel framework and this is one of the queries I use:

```
$users= DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('users')->where('status', 'active')->get()->all();
```

I have also try without framework, but the result is the same:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=(local)\sqlexpress;Database=db");
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active'");
$query->execute();
$users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Regards

Comment: Is slow only the first connection or all of them?

Comment: All of them are slow

Comment: can you put the code you are using?

Comment: I am using Laravel framework and this is one of the queries I use:

`code`$users= DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('users')->where('status', 'active')->get()->all();`/code`


I have also try without framework, but the result is the same:
`code`
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=(local)\sqlexpress;Database=db");
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active'");
$query->execute();
$users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
`/code`

Comment: Please edit the question, it's cleaner and you will avoid negative votes.

Comment: Ok, edited. Sorry.